# User-specified sort order in Firebase

Tags: ios, sorting, firebase, transactions, firebase-realtime-database

In an iOS app I would like to give the user the possibility to change the sort order of items in a table (by dragging the row and dropping it at the new location).

I structured the data in Firebase like this:

```
{
  "items": {
    "id1": {
      "title": "A",
      "sortOrder": 2
    },
    "id2": {
      "title": "B",
      "sortOrder": 1
    },
    "id3": …
  }
}
```

With a queryOrderedByChild("sortOrder") I get the items in the correct order B, A, …

Updating the data after the user changed the sort order, is not so easy though:

- Let's say the user switches A and B, then the sortOrder of A and B must be changed "simultaneously" in a transaction. Moreover, if let's say F is moved in front of A, all items in-between must be adjusted by + 1.
- If a new item is appended, we must ensure that it gets the next highest sort order, so I guess we would have to determine the highest sort order, add the item with sortOrder + 1. If in the meantime another item has been added with this sort order, we must reject the first attempt, retry with +2, +3 etc..

I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing this, is it? Is it possible to achieve this behaviour with Firebase transactions?

Comment: Have you tried adding a listner to indexPath.row and updating your DB, when it changes for a specific row/? Havent checked it but just a thought...:)

Comment: Thank you! What I do now is: After the user has moved a row, I reorder the items in the model accordingly (plain array). Then I use the array to update all items in Firebase at once with sortOrder = index in the array. Works like a charm.